# Default Activity Not Found in android studio version 1.2.2

Tags: android

I am new to android application development and i am following the video tutorials of New Boston. My appication gave error in the emulator "application closed unexpectedly" but when i tried to run it again it gave **Error : Default activity not found**.

After spending hours of time on google and stack overflow i realised it is related to android manifest.

so this is my manifest file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shubhangkhattar.newboston" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.shubhangkhattar.newboston.SPLASH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.shubhangkhattar.newboston.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.shubhangkhattar.newboston.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I have already tried invalidate catches/restart and sync project with gradle files.**

Comment: Paste the complete logs here.  Is this class present in your project `com.example.shubhangkhattar.newboston.SPLASH` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
    <action android:name="com.example.shubhangkhattar.newboston.SPLASH"/>
```

To

```
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
```

[Intents reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)